# Cannot find table 0

Tags: sql, datagridview, dataset, dataadapter

I'm getting this error when I try to insert into table pay_cheque any help

```
private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string s = "insert into pay_cheque values('Sai','Sai','Sai','Sai','10.2','1989/2/3','Sai')";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Book;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(s, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "x");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: Haven't worked with `SqlDataAdapter` in a while, but why are you trying to fill a newly created `DataSet` with an insert command?  Wouldn't you want to use the existing `DataSet`?

Comment: I did't get you but when i used command object it is working

Comment: Try to use the name instead of index 0.

Comment: yup its working could you tell me why i got that error

Answer (score 0):

The **Fill** method will retrieve data of a query and fill a dataset. However, you are not using a query statement. You can only do that with a SELECT statement, then you can retrieve the data and fill a dataset.

To retrieve the data, use a SELECT statement based on the primary key after you have inserted it. Even though doing so is pretty useless in my opinion.